# IntervalSlider MinIntervalSize dependent on another control

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I would like to achieve the effect of the DynamicModule below using a Manipulate. Several of my attempts failed.  I could not get MinIntervalSize to recognize the dynamic variable. Is is possible to do this with Manipulate?

```
DynamicModule[{intv, w = 10, xwin = 10}, Panel[Column[{
Dynamic@
 TextCell["WindowSize: " <> ToString[Dynamic[Evaluate@xwin]]],
Dynamic@
 IntervalSlider[Dynamic[intv], {0, 100, 1}, 
  MinIntervalSize -> Evaluate[xwin], Method -> "Push"],
Slider[Dynamic[xwin], {5, 50, 5}]
}]]]
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this works, unless I have misunderstood the requirements:

```
Manipulate[
 TextCell["WindowSize: " <> ToString[xwin]],
 {intv, IntervalSlider[#, {0, 100, 1}, MinIntervalSize -> xwin, Method -> "Push"] &},
 {xwin, 5, 50, 5}]
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Is there a place where this form of a Manipulate control is documented (i.e. giving the control itself as pure function)?

Comment: @JohnMcGee, it is in the `Manipulate` documentation though not particularly prominent. The general form is listed in the table at the top of the details section as "*{u,func}* - create an arbitrary control from a function"

Comment: Thanks, this is a big help. I am new to interface programming in Mathematica and still learning the subtleties of Dynamic and the magic that Manipulate does under the covers and the limitations that this imposes.